# Extract certificate name with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, x509certificate

I need to parse a string that can be one of the followings:

```
"CN=bbb1, OU=b, O=b, L=b, S=b, C=US"        //expected result bbb1
"CN=*.host.com, OU=b, O=b, L=b, S=b, C=US"  //expected result *.host.com
"CN = *.host.com "                          //expected result *.host.com
"CN = bbb1    "                             //expected result bbb1
```

I wrote the following Parsing function for that:

```
public static string GetCertificateName(string certSubject)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex;
        try
        {
            regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"CN\s*=\s*(?<name>\w+)");
            var match = regex.Match(certSubject);
            return match.Groups["name"].Value;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    return "Can't parse";
} 
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetCertificateName("CN=bbb1, OU=b, O=b, L=b, S=b, C=US")); //bbb1
    Console.WriteLine(GetCertificateName("CN = bbb3   "));//bb33
    Console.WriteLine(GetCertificateName("CN =  bbb4\n\t "));//bbb4
    Console.WriteLine(GetCertificateName("CN=*.host.com"));//empty string!!! != *.host.com
    Console.ReadLine( );
}
```

Please help me to improve my parsing function so GetCertificateName("CN=*.host.com") call will return *.host.com
Thanks a lot,
Natalie

Comment: `Please help me improve` What needs improving, exactly?

Comment: `\w+` doesn't match `*`. Change it to `\S+` or `[\w*]+` and it should work.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/LsTjYb/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `CN` is in the *beginning* of the string (as we can see in all the examples) you can try *Linq* solution (start at `=`, stop at `,`, trim the middle)

```
  string source = "CN  = *.host.com ";

  string result = string.Concat(source
      .SkipWhile(c => c != '=')
      .Skip(1)
      .TakeWhile(c => c != ','))
    .Trim();
```

Or even good old `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
  string source = "CN  =*.host.com,";

  int start = source.IndexOf('=') + 1;
  int stop = start <= 0 ? - 1 : source.IndexOf(',', start);

  string result = start <= 0 ? null 
    : stop >= 0 ? source.Substring(start, stop - start).Trim()
    : source.Substring(start).Trim();
```

Comment: Might want to clarify that the "CM" field is guaranteed to be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Abion47: I really do want to mentioning this key condition in the answer. Thank you! Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

My solution that works :)

```
public static string GetCertificateName(string certSubject)
{
    //"CN=bbb1, OU=b, O=b, L=b, S=b, C=US"  
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex;
    try
    {
        regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"CN\s*=\s*(?<name>\*?\.?\w*\.?\w+)");
        var match = regex.Match(certSubject);
        return match.Groups["name"].Value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return "Can't parse";
}
```

Comment: Can you have an input like `"CN  =*.host.*,"`? In this case, the match is `"*.host"`

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for your reply, in my case i can assume that the input won't be *.host.* but i really didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer without using of regular expressions:

```
  public static string Parsing(string certSubject)
    {
        string[] strArr = certSubject.Split(new char[] { '=', ' ', '\t', '\n',',' });
    string subject = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (strArr[i].Equals("cn", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if ((i + 1) < strArr.Length)
            {

                subject = strArr[i + 1];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (subject.Length > 0)
    {
        return subject;
    }
    return "Can't parse";
}
```

Comment: `string[] strArr = certSubject.Split(new char[] { '=', ' ', '\t', '\n', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` will filter out all empty chunks

Comment: Can you have an imput like this `"CN=file:\\c:\Program Files\MyFile.txt"`; it's the *space* (between `Program` and `Files`) that spoils the fan

Comment: You are right, i will stick to the regular expression solution.